# vncviewer fails to connect (fedora-29)

Tags: ssl, vnc

So I already fixed this but thought I'd drop the solution here for posterity.

I have 2 fedora-29 boxes. I want to use (tiger-)vncserver and (tiger-)vncviewer in the usual way. Trouble is, it was consistently failing to make the connection:

```
$ vncviewer <server-name>
....
 CConnection: Server supports RFB protocol version 3.8
 CConnection: Using RFB protocol version 3.8
 CConnection: Choosing security type VeNCrypt(19)
 CVeNCrypt:   Choosing security type TLSVnc (258)
 TLS:         TLS Handshake failed: An illegal TLS extension was received.

Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Similar things happen with rimmini.

Solution follows ...

Answer (score 0):

Eliminating TLSVnc from the list of allowed security types gave me a win:

```
$ vncviewer -FullScreen -SecurityTypes None,VncAuth,Plain,TLSNone,TLSPlain,X509None,X509Vnc,X509Plain <server-name>
```

I'm very interested if anyone has a better solution eg fixing my TLS - I have no idea what I might have broken. A clue - I recently upgraded the remote end (where I run vncserver) from f-24 (where it worked flawlessly) to f-29. I made no changes on the workstation end (ie where I run vncviewer).